# Make list of videos available on device

Tags: android, file, list, search, video

How can I search the internal and external storage card for video files and make a ListView out of it ?
I want to make a list of videos available on device in video player app. So that user can select any video and play it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you don't search the sdcard but instead use mediastore for it because when the phone starts android devices search the whole sdcard and creates a database of all media files.That database is the mediastore.....from there you can fetch the videos you want and add it in a list view